# MySQL function to pull parent instead of current row

Tags: php, mysql

There's a function in MySQL that I can't remember what it's called.... if you have the following table, it'll pull the data from the `parent_id` row instead of the current row when the `parent_id` is not 0

```
    id     parent_id      name
-------------------------------------------
    1      0              MyRow1
    2      1              MyRow2
```

And... is it possible for me to determine if it's pulling the parent row or the current row by flagging a `used_reference` to 1 or 0?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function, but you can do it like this:

```
SELECT  IF(c.parent_id = 0, p.name, c.name),
        c.parent_id <> 0 AS used_reference
FROM    mytable c
LEFT JOIN
        mytable p
ON      p.id = c.parent_id
```

Comment: @Webnet: as you say. Tell me when you find it if you please.

Comment: I think it's this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce, but I can't think of how I used it before...

Comment: @Webnet: this function returns first non-`NULL` value from the argument list. You can use it instead of `IF`, however, it will behave incorrectly if you `name` fields are nullable. And you still need a `JOIN`.